# Instance "Main" Method Not Running When Called from Another Class

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm learning Java and experimenting with Javafx in netbeans.

I am running the sqlite tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

When set up as a lone-file it works fine of course.

I'm setting it up in a test project "testDB" and for some reason when I initiate the class the class itself is recognized, but main() is not running.

Here is the testdb file itself:

### testDB.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sqlitetest;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 */
public class testDB {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //THESE STEPS ARE ON NOT RUNNING (compiles without errors)

        System.out.println("testing");
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");    

    }

    public void makeStuff(){

    }

}
```

### sqlitetest.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sqlitetest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 */
public class Sqlitetest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testDB test = new testDB();
        test.makeStuff();
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: That may be. I set that up thinking that main is fired on initiation, and hence any code I put in there would also fire. I might be misunderstood then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between a constructor and a main method.

- A main method is only invoked when you start the JVM, running that specific class (or if you invoke it explicitly elsewhere).
- A constructor is invoked when you create an instance of the class, like you are doing here.

In `testdb`, change:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

to

```
public testdb() {
```

Alternatively, invoke `testdb.main(args)` (or with some other parameter) in `Sqlitetest.main`.

Comment: Correct. `main` is not called when a class is instantiated. It is called when you execute a java program with the `java` command. When `new` operator is used, the constructor is called.

Comment: @Takendarkk thanks. I've added a bit more info to the answer about the difference.